# Android/Java - Can't set ad size

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, adview

I am trying to use AdMob in Android and am following tutorials. I have successfully downloaded, installed and added the Google Play Services library. Nearly everything seems fine.

However Eclipse stubbornly gives a red underline under the "adView.setAdSize" bit. The error message says "The method setAdSize(AdSize) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (AdSize)". I don't see what's wrong, that code is in line with all tutorials and documentation I can find, and why would setAdSize(AdSize) not take in AdSize as an argument? That doesn't make sense to me.

Unfortunately setting the ad size is necessary for the code to run so I can't just remove that bit. Relevant code is below. Thanks to anyone that can help.

```
...
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        // Create the adView.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ID REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS");

        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using other size than smart_banner?

Comment: Smart banner is the one I want, but here is what happened when I tried all the other ones:

adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER); --> Same as in main post.

· adView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER); --> Red underline under FULL_BANNER. Error message is "FULL_BANNER cannot be resolved or is not a field".

LARGE_BANNER, LEADERBOARD, MEDIUM_RECTANGLE and WIDE_SKYSCRAPER have the same error as in FULL_BANNER above.

Comment: Are you using the last version of the lib?

Comment: I downloaded it only a few hours ago. Android SDK Manager says I have Google Play Services revision 21, and Google Repository revision 13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
```

For:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
```